# How to prevent jump on an anchor click?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I use `e.preventDefault();` to disable default anchor behaviour.

Is there a way to prevent only jump action to a target on click?

I tried:

```
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var link = $('a');
  $('a').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = "#"+link.attr("href");
  });
```

But it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/ynts/LgcmB/.

Answer (score 28):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var link = $('a');
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = link.attr("href");
    window.location = hash;
  });
});
```

You also have to specify event argument in the function. By naming it as `e` or `event` and then you can manipulate it.

Comment: Was just about to comment on the lack of explanation for the missing event, but there it was, +1.

Comment: heheheh :P I will never miss descriptions in my answers :D

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no jump action and no url update. I want to have `jsfiddle.net/ynts/Jgkmt/embedded/result/#anchor` after click.

Comment: edited my answer :D It may not work in the jsFiddle because they use iframes!

Comment: Once `window.location` is set, a jump to `#anchor` happens :(.

Comment: can you explain a little more?

Comment: @AspiringAqib I put this example from jsFiddle to [test_1.html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/983140/@/stackoverflow.com/14185974/test_1.html). The link is clicked → url in adress bar is added with `#anchor` (on `window.location = hash;`) → jump to `p#anchor` happens. So all steps of default click action on an anchor link are here. My idea was to get only `#anchor` added to page adress in adress bar and no page scroll to `p#anchor`.

Comment: well you can use, this plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ and add this code to jQuery:
`$(window).hashchange( function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });` I think it will work and if worked then don't forget to do something ;)

Comment: @AspiringAqib still no luck: [test_2.html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/983140/@/stackoverflow.com/14185974/test_2.html).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22347/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-ynt)

Comment: `<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      var link = $('a');
      $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        hash = link.attr("href");
        window.location = hash;
      });
    });
    $(window).hashchange( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
</script>` You were adding that function in other event which occurs on click!

Comment: @AspiringAqib I tried this variant, too. [It doesn't resolve the issue.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/983140/%40/stackoverflow.com/14185974/test_3.html)

Comment: oh buddy then I have also never tried these things but can you explain why you wanna stop it to do that?

Comment: @AspiringAqib I use a script for tabs that works with anchors. It works smooth. But I want to add `#href-value` to a page adress in adress bar when a tab is clicked. However, once URL is updated, a page jumps to `div#href-value`. So I lose "smoothness" of tabs behavior.

Comment: `window.location.hash = hash` is more safe than `window.location = hash` isn't it?

Comment: Seems like an obtrusive script behavior to intercept the click event and prevent it, then fish the href value out of the attribute and assign it the to the window location.

Perhaps a better way:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34544031/1467810

Answer (score 15):

This is the only solution I could come up with that works consistently across all desktop and mobile browsers or webviews with various client UI libraries and frameworks. By getting the window coordinates before scrolling occurs we can revert and maintain the current scroll position.

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var x = window.pageXOffset,
        y = window.pageYOffset;
    $(window).one('scroll', function () {
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
    })
});
```

Comment: I tried different solutions but your solution is very good. it worked on searching also

Comment: This had same affect for me as just using e.preventDefault();

Comment: This will not cause wierd behavior within a WKWebView!

Comment: @Daniel and @ANGOmarcello that's the idea : "Is there a way to prevent only jump action to a target on click?" The event default behavior is not prevented via `e.preventDefault()`  nor is `e.stopPropagation()` occurring. Only the UI jump behavior is prevented via scroll position value revert before painting as asked.

Answer (score 5):

To **only** prevent the "jump" you have to use different id for the target element than what is specified in the anchor.

e.g. for a link to a new tab use,

```
<a href="#new" />
```

and for the target element mask the id

```
<div id="new-tab"></div>
```

Then in your script append the mask to the real hash, and use it to get the element.

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function(){
    var hash = this.location.hash;
    var mytab = $(hash + "-tab");
});
```

This preserves the hash location changes in browser history that can be controlled by the back/forward buttons, and detected on page load with the `hashchange` event if user enters the page with hash specified.

Comment: Thanks so much for this comment. I did this long ago and couldn't figure out for the life of me remember what I did to solve the stupid cross-page reload scrolling issues. Your answer reminded me of the good ol' masking method!

Comment: Very helpful in different circumstances. E.g. define a boolean on page load, change the anchor, prevent the jump. After page load handle clicks on inner anchors as usual.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind an onclick event to anchor and specify `return false;` as a result.
The `return false;` statement causes default click behaviour (jump) would not work.
You can find more info here: [How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page/17950528#17950528)

Comment: In jQuery, it might look like this: 

```$("a[href='#']").on('click', function(event) {
  return false;
 });```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the event on the function.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;
var link = $('a');
//pass event here
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = "#"+link.attr("href");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, while I was typing I seen another answer had been posted.  Good answer Aspiring Aqib.

Comment: well, i can't understand why i get exhausted while answering if i see, somebody else also have answered. "1 new answer to this question. Click to Load". :D

Answer (score 1):

After first trying the other answers on this page, this was all I needed:

```js
  $('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match` with `^` to detect starting with `#`

```
$("a:link").on("click", function(e){
    if($(this).attr("href").match("^#")) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //some other stuff you want to do with the hash, like smooth scroll to anchor
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Add any string after the hash:

```
<a href="#anystring">
```

Comment: The OP is passing `hash = "#"+link.attr("href");`