# Smooth scroll to anchor from url using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, scroll, anchor

I'm creating a portfolio website and I've got the work section showing half way down the home page. So when you click 'work' in the navigation it scrolls to the work section of the page using jQuery. However when clicking on the work button from the about page it just jumps to the work section, rather than loading the homepage then scrolling to it.

Say the button on the about page is `href="index.html#work"`. Anyone know how to make it load the home page and then scroll to the work anchor?

Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

How about prevent default behavior when the document's loaded, then execute function.

[How to prevent jump on an anchor click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185974/how-to-prevent-jump-on-an-anchor-click)

[How to disable anchor "jump" when loading a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659072/jquery-disable-anchor-jump-when-loading-a-page/17950528#17950528)