# This demo of jquery mobile panels always makes the page jump when you open the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make the main body of the page stay still when you open the menu? So you can close it and remain where you are?

```
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/panel-fixed/
```

Comment: I noticed this too. Let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185974/how-to-prevent-jump-on-an-anchor-click