# Bootstrap 3 Tabs - link from another page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code which enables me to link to a specific tab from another page. The only problem is that when the link is clicked the page is loaded and then scrolled down to where the DIV is located. I want it to just load the page at the top.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  // Javascript to enable link to tab
  var url = document.location.toString();
  if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href=#'+url.split('#')[1]+']').tab('show') ;
  }

  // Change hash for page-reload
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  });
});
</script>
```

The hyperlink back to the page with the tabs is as follows.

```
<a href="../view_mail/#two" class="btn btn-theme">Close</a>
```

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way to do this but try just scroll to the top after a click.

```
$( "body" ).scrollTop(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following unfortunately will likely not work:

> e.preventDefault();

([How to prevent jump on an anchor click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185974/how-to-prevent-jump-on-an-anchor-click))

The above will not solve the problem because, I believe, preventDefault does not apply to updating **location.hash** ([How can I update window.location.hash without jumping the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document)).

Alternatively you can use the scrollTop method, but you may see a scroll jump temporarily with this method:

> $("body").scrollTop(0);

In modern browsers, you can use the History Api ([How can I update window.location.hash without jumping the document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870057/how-can-i-update-window-location-hash-without-jumping-the-document)).

Answer (score 0):

If you prevent the default event the hash wont be attached to the url. If you use the scrollTop "hack" the user might experience a glitch. Try using the history API:

```
history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');

if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#myhash');
}
else {
    location.hash = '#myhash';
}
```

I got this from: http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/