# Preventing anchor tag jump for hidden divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a staff layout page, with hidden divs appearing with an anchor tag and :target when a staff member's picture or name is clicked. However, the default anchor jump behavior is much too... jumpy (edit: staccato and jarring for the user's eyes to easily follow) for this to work cleanly.

I've perused the [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185974/how-to-prevent-jump-on-an-anchor-click) on this topic, but just can't seem to implement a solution that works.

This is the snippet that I've been trying to implement:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  var link = $('a');
  $('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    hash = link.attr("href");
    window.location = hash;
  });
});
```

```css
.teamGrid {
  display: inline-block;
}
.teamGrid .staffHidden {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.teamGrid .staffHidden p {
  color: #000000
}
.teamPerson {
  width: 33%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
.teamPerson:first-child .staffHidden {
  left: 0;
}
.teamPerson:nth-child(2) .staffHidden {
  left: -100%;
}
.teamPerson:nth-child(3) .staffHidden {
  left: -200%;
}
#janet,
#fred,
#shirley {
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 0px;
  width: 569px;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: max-height, visibility;
  transition-duration: 1s, 0s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}
#janet:target,
#fred:target,
#shirley:target {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 600px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  margin: 4px 0px 4px 0px;
  padding: 4px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teamGrid">
  <div class="teamPerson">
    <p></p>
    <a href="#shirley">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />

      <h3>Shirley</h3>
      <p>Founder</p>
    </a>
    <div id="shirley" class="staffHidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum shirley Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et mauris sagittis felis fringilla lacinia ut ac ipsum. In ac mollis sem. Pellentesque fringilla felis vel rutrum dapibus. Duis cursus sed magna et malesuada. Etiam
        auctor vestibulum diam, pretium molestie tortor ultrices nec. Aliquam finibus maximus nulla, vitae tincidunt lorem molestie a. Ut non dolor quis dui euismod bibendum. Quisque eu diam sem. Curabitur sed eros facilisis, facilisis elit sed, finibus
        massa. Nulla tincidunt vulputate ipsum non feugiat. Donec elementum dui a orci hendrerit tempus. Cras egestas euismod risus in placerat. Maecenas dictum, quam vitae varius malesuada, metus risus eleifend est, sit amet interdum est leo vitae urna.
        Suspendisse et nisi metus. In vestibulum mollis magna a consequat. Vivamus fringilla interdum tellus sit amet auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus a luctus massa. Integer eget dui lacinia orci venenatis iaculis. Curabitur facilisis
        mi id interdum efficitur. Etiam a nulla ac augue molestie gravida. Nullam non ligula sit amet tortor faucibus ultrices. Curabitur consectetur commodo nulla, vel cursus augue consequat suscipit. Aenean blandit libero in odio auctor lobortis. Praesent
        luctus felis a erat mollis, sed volutpat urna faucibus. Nam sed sem vel nisl mollis dignissim vel eget urna. Nam semper nisi ut maximus iaculis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="teamPerson">
    <p>
      <a href="#fred" class="noJump">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
        <h3>Fred</h3>
        <p>President and COO</a>
      </p>
      <div id="fred" class="staffHidden">
        <p>Lorem ipsum fred Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et mauris sagittis felis fringilla lacinia ut ac ipsum. In ac mollis sem. Pellentesque fringilla felis vel rutrum dapibus. Duis cursus sed magna et malesuada. Etiam
          auctor vestibulum diam, pretium molestie tortor ultrices nec. Aliquam finibus maximus nulla, vitae tincidunt lorem molestie a. Ut non dolor quis dui euismod bibendum. Quisque eu diam sem. Curabitur sed eros facilisis, facilisis elit sed, finibus
          massa. Nulla tincidunt vulputate ipsum non feugiat. Donec elementum dui a orci hendrerit tempus. Cras egestas euismod risus in placerat. Maecenas dictum, quam vitae varius malesuada, metus risus eleifend est, sit amet interdum est leo vitae
          urna. Suspendisse et nisi metus. In vestibulum mollis magna a consequat. Vivamus fringilla interdum tellus sit amet auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus a luctus massa. Integer eget dui lacinia orci venenatis iaculis. Curabitur
          facilisis mi id interdum efficitur. Etiam a nulla ac augue molestie gravida. Nullam non ligula sit amet tortor faucibus ultrices. Curabitur consectetur commodo nulla, vel cursus augue consequat suscipit. Aenean blandit libero in odio auctor
          lobortis. Praesent luctus felis a erat mollis, sed volutpat urna faucibus. Nam sed sem vel nisl mollis dignissim vel eget urna. Nam semper nisi ut maximus iaculis.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="teamPerson">
    <p>
      <a href="#janet">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </p>
    <h3>Janet</h3>
    <p>Chief Engagement Officer</a>
    </p>
    <div id="janet" class="staffHidden">
      <p>Lorem ipsum janet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et mauris sagittis felis fringilla lacinia ut ac ipsum. In ac mollis sem. Pellentesque fringilla felis vel rutrum dapibus. Duis cursus sed magna et malesuada. Etiam
        auctor vestibulum diam, pretium molestie tortor ultrices nec. Aliquam finibus maximus nulla, vitae tincidunt lorem molestie a. Ut non dolor quis dui euismod bibendum. Quisque eu diam sem. Curabitur sed eros facilisis, facilisis elit sed, finibus
        massa. Nulla tincidunt vulputate ipsum non feugiat. Donec elementum dui a orci hendrerit tempus. Cras egestas euismod risus in placerat. Maecenas dictum, quam vitae varius malesuada, metus risus eleifend est, sit amet interdum est leo vitae urna.
        Suspendisse et nisi metus. In vestibulum mollis magna a consequat. Vivamus fringilla interdum tellus sit amet auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus a luctus massa. Integer eget dui lacinia orci venenatis iaculis. Curabitur facilisis
        mi id interdum efficitur. Etiam a nulla ac augue molestie gravida. Nullam non ligula sit amet tortor faucibus ultrices. Curabitur consectetur commodo nulla, vel cursus augue consequat suscipit. Aenean blandit libero in odio auctor lobortis. Praesent
        luctus felis a erat mollis, sed volutpat urna faucibus. Nam sed sem vel nisl mollis dignissim vel eget urna. Nam semper nisi ut maximus iaculis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance, and I apologize for any blatant errors due to amateur skills.

Comment: now I don't know if you add a `position: fixed;` at the hidden elements CSS should do the trick... I will test here.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work here, give it a try.

Comment: what does `much too jumpy` mean? Not clear what you are wanting to accomplish

Comment: thanks Giovanni. `position: fixed;` does work, however I'll be adding rows of staff underneath, and would have to animate them to move down with the hidden div -- something 'position: relative;' does automatically.

Comment: you trying to do something like this, as in "smooth scrolling"? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: thanks Rob, that would definitely be a nice effect and makes things much smoother. Right now, adding that code breaks the `target:` behavior and the hidden divs do not appear, but I'll dive in and see if I can correct that.

Comment: Woo hoo! Thanks so much all. The smooth scrolling code just needed a few edits to append the hash anchor to the url: `location.href = $(this).attr('href');`, and I could also play with the offset to reduce scroll movement `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200`.