# jquery- Scroll Automatically to the top of the Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run a function when i click a anchor tag.

```
$("#addItemMedicine")
.click(function () {
   $.get("/Referred/AddMedicineNewRow",
    function (data) {
     $("#MedicineEditorRows").append(data);
    })
   .fail(function (xhr, err) {
  alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
                        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
                    });
            });
```

When run this function , Scroll Automatically to the top of the Page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).
Just select one of your existing elements, or add fictional.

```
function scrollToTop() {
    $('body').append($('<div id="zero" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;left:0;top:0"></div>'));
    $('#zero')[0].scrollIntoView();
    $('#zero').remove();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I can change scroll position to my elemnt after run function, but i want to stop scroll.

Comment: It's not obvious from your post . how to stop scroll ~ 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185974/how-to-prevent-jump-on-an-anchor-click