# Bootstrap tab jumping with Angular

Tags: angularjs

When clicking a tab on Twitter Bootstrap, the page jumps down to the tab anchor. I'd like to disable this using the code as shown here:
[Twitter Bootstrap Tabs href="#" anchor tag jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548617/twitter-bootstrap-tabs-href-anchor-tag-jumping)

However I'm using Angular - where would I place this code so that it runs for every bootstrap tab as & when it gets loaded with a new page?

---

From what I understand, the issue is that ui-router is pushing the anchor into the url, as it thinks it's a change in state, and this is causing the page to jump to the anchor. So I guess I'm asking how to exclude these tabs from ui-router?

Currently I'm using the double-hash solution in the above link, but I'd prefer a cleaner solution which just excludes the tabs from ui-router. Another solution would be to override the action using stateChangeSuccess, but that's also not ideal.

Comment: Which router are you using? ui.router or angular's ngRoute?

Comment: get rid of using bootstrap.js and use angular-bootstrap instead. If each tab represents a route you would only need to use tabs css though. Overall problem is not well defined

Comment: @charlietfl - I am using angular-bootstrap. The tabs are all on the same route, they each show different lists of relevant data. Not sure what you mean by only using tabs css?

Comment: Well I'm confused too since link in question refers to using bootstrap.js. Create a plunker demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl I think it's because I'm using ui-router that it's putting the anchor in the url, which causes the page to jump to the anchor. I can't get a decent plunkr to work because you can't really use anchors in plunkr..? i.e. the anchor doesn't work because it doesn't change the plunkr.co. url.

Comment: router works fine in plunker full screen view. angular-ui tabs don't use href so still not clear what issue is. If you are wanting one tab per route... don't need to use tabs directive.... just use tabs html and css and set content based on route

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [UI Router State Change Hooks](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)
Maybe you can tap into the `$stateChangeSuccess` event and execute the code here. I'm assuming that each tab is a unique state similar to this website [AngularJS website with tabs and UI Router](http://angularjstutor.com/coursedes). If not you may want to consider designing it in this manner. The code is here [Code for AngularJS Tutor website](https://github.com/sidazad/angularjstutor)